# ETL conector from a Postgres Dump File

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, odbc, sql-server-data-tools

After spending a time looking for an answer for my question, i decided to ask for help.

I have a dump file, from postgres back and need to upload this for a SQL Server database.

First choice: installed a PostgreSQL server, restored the dump file, odbc conector for ETL Process in SSDT and worked fine and nice. Negative points: Backup restoring a little bit slow. Need to restore backup out of SSDT, so process is not completely automated.

What I seek as an alternative: A script task, or some other alternative, to read the dump file and convert this for CSV files. Not success in this alternative.

Other choice: An ODBC conector to read the dump file directly in SSDT and upload this to my SQL Server directly, also, unsuccessful.

Do you have any other option for me, considering that I would like to keep PostgreSQL out of this possibility. Would like to use, just SSDT and SQL Server.

Upload data from Psql dump file, direclty to SQL Server.

Comment: The only thing that can process a Postgres dump file is Postgres. If  it's a SQL dump that uses `INSERT` statements rather than `copy` you _might_ be able to make it runnable on SQL Server using some search & replace, but I'd say that's more complicated and error prone than simply restoring the dump to Postgres. Not sure why you can't use `pg_restore` (or at least `psql`) though.

Comment: Add a new question: Is it possible I restore a database with a dos command line? So, I could execute this restore with a .bat file.

Comment: Sure, using `pg_restore` or `psql` depending on how the dump was taken